# How to open a diff at the position of the current buffer?

Tags: navigation, diff

Emacs has a useful feature to jump to the line (via `diff-goto-source-and-close`).

Is there a way to do the reverse with `vc-root-diff` or something similar?

That is to open a diff, jumping to the current line of code (if it's been modified or added?).

Comment: I suggest you file a feature request with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  IIRC Dan Nicolaescu asked for this some years ago and had some prototype code working, so maybe he now has something working reliably.

Comment: Done: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=36526 (also wrote this feature https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51346)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: this is now a package: [diff-at-point](https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-diff-at-point)

---

This solution parses the diff hunks to lookup a buffer location in the diff.

By default, if the current location isn't part of the diff, the closest line in the diff is used (unless the option argument `strict` isn't `nil`).

```lisp
(defun diff-at-point-file-line-to-point
  (current-filename-relative current-line current-column &optional strict)
  "This can be used to navigate to a point in a diff buffer.

Given the file, line and column in the original (non-diff) file,
this returns the point in the diff buffer or nil if it can't be found.

This can be used to implement a utility to open a diff buffer,
then navigate to the point the user was viewing.
However this function doesn't make any change the the buffer state,
that's up to the caller to implement.

CURRENT-FILENAME-RELATIVE the filename to look-up in the diff.
Typically this is the filename of the current buffer,
relative to the repository root.

Arguments CURRENT-LINE & CURRENT-COLUMN define the location in the file.
Typically this is taken from the current `point'.

When STRICT is enabled, only return a result if the line exists in the diff,
otherwise return a point in the closest hunk."
  (save-excursion
    (if
      (not
        (re-search-forward
          (concat
            ;; Prefix '+++ '.
            "^"
            "\\-\\-\\-[[:blank:]]+.*\n"
            "\\+\\+\\+[[:blank:]]+"
            ;; Optional 'b/'.
            "\\(\\|b/\\)"
            (regexp-quote current-filename-relative)
            ;; Optional ' (some text)'
            ;; Subversion quirk.
            "\\(\\|[[:blank:]]+.*\\)\n"
            "@@[[:blank:]]+.*[[:blank:]]@@"
            ;; may have trailing text, ignore this.
            ) nil t 1))
      (error "Unable to find filename in diff: %S" current-filename-relative)

      (beginning-of-line)
      (let
        (
          ;; Next file or end of document.
          (point-found nil)
          ;; Fallback point closest to the hunk,
          ;; used if 'current-line' isn't inside the hunk in the diff.
          ;;
          ;; The fallback uses either the beginning or end of the hunk.
          (fallback-point-begin nil)
          (fallback-point-end nil)
          (fallback-point-is-begin nil)
          ;; The distance of the fallback point to the line we're looking for.
          (fallback-delta-lines nil)
          ;; Find the next hunk or file max, to restrict the search.
          (current-filename-diff-point-max
            (save-excursion
              (if
                (re-search-forward
                  (concat
                    "\\(^\\)"
                    ;; Optional, don't capture, ignore.
                    ;; Git uses: "diff ..." & "index ..."
                    ;; Subversion uses: "Index ..." & "===...".
                    ;;
                    ;; So use any non-blank line start except for '-' & '+'.
                    "\\(?:[^\\-\\+[:blank:]]+.*\n\\)+?"
                    ;; Prefix '+++ '.
                    "\\-\\-\\-[[:blank:]]+.*\n"
                    "\\+\\+\\+[[:blank:]]+.*\n"
                    ;; May have trailing text which can be safely ignored.
                    "@@[[:blank:]]+.*[[:blank:]]@@")
                  nil t 1)
                (match-beginning 0)
                (point-max)))))

        ;; Now search for the current hunk.
        (save-excursion
          (while
            (and
              (eq point-found nil)
              (re-search-forward
                (concat
                  "^\\(@@\\)[[:blank:]]+"
                  ;; Previous (ignore).
                  "\\-"
                  "\\([[:digit:]]+\\)\\,\\([[:digit:]]+\\)"
                  "[[:blank:]]+"
                  ;; Current (use).
                  "\\+"
                  "\\([[:digit:]]+\\)\\,\\([[:digit:]]+\\)"
                  "[[:blank:]]+@@")
                current-filename-diff-point-max t 1))
            (let*
              (
                (diff-hunk-point (match-beginning 1))
                (diff-hunk-begin
                  (string-to-number
                    (buffer-substring-no-properties
                      (match-beginning 4)
                      (match-end 4))))
                (diff-hunk-lines
                  (string-to-number
                    (buffer-substring-no-properties
                      (match-beginning 5)
                      (match-end 5))))
                (diff-hunk-end (+ diff-hunk-begin diff-hunk-lines)))
              ;; We have something like this:
              ;; @@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
              ;; string-to-number
              ;; (message "%S %S" diff-hunk-begin diff-hunk-end)

              ;; If the last hunk was set as the fallback, use this chink as the
              ;; end of that fallback.
              (when (and
                      (eq fallback-point-end nil)
                      (not (eq fallback-point-begin nil)))
                (setq fallback-point-end diff-hunk-point))

              ;; Scan down the the line...
              (cond
                ((< current-line diff-hunk-begin)
                  (let ((delta (- diff-hunk-begin current-line)))
                    (when (or
                            (eq fallback-delta-lines nil)
                            (> fallback-delta-lines delta))
                      (setq fallback-point-begin diff-hunk-point)
                      (setq fallback-point-is-begin t)
                      (setq fallback-delta-lines delta)
                      ;; Set next iteration.
                      (setq fallback-point-end nil))))
                ((>= current-line diff-hunk-end)
                  (let ((delta (- current-line diff-hunk-end)))
                    (when (or
                            (eq fallback-delta-lines nil)
                            (> fallback-delta-lines delta))
                      (setq fallback-point-begin diff-hunk-point)
                      (setq fallback-point-is-begin nil)
                      (setq fallback-delta-lines delta)
                      ;; Set next iteration.
                      (setq fallback-point-end nil))))
                (t
                  (let ((diff-line-current diff-hunk-begin))
                    (forward-line)
                    ;; Avoid eternal loop (for mal-formed diffs).
                    (while (eq point-found nil)
                      (let ((c (char-after (point))))
                        (cond
                          ((memq c '(?\s ?+))
                            (when (eq diff-line-current current-line)
                              (setq point-found (+ 1 (point) current-column)))
                            (setq diff-line-current (+ 1 diff-line-current)))
                          ((eq c ?-)
                            nil)
                          (t
                            (error "Malformed diff, unexpected character %S" c))))
                      (forward-line))))))))

        ;; May be nil, return either way.
        (if strict
          point-found
          (or
            point-found
            ;; Use the beginning or end of the hunk.
            (save-excursion
              (if fallback-point-is-begin
                (progn
                  (goto-char fallback-point-begin)
                  (forward-line 1)
                  (forward-char)
                  )
                (progn
                  (goto-char (or fallback-point-end current-filename-diff-point-max))
                  (forward-line -1)
                  (forward-char)))
              ;; fallback-point-end
              (point))))))))
```

This is a utility function which uses the function above to open diff and jump to the point (if possible).

```lisp
(defun vc-root-diff-fullscreen-and-jump-to-point (&optional branch) "
Open a diff of the repository in the current frame.
Jumping to the file, then line if possible.
"
  (interactive)
  (let
    (
      (pop-up-windows nil)
      (current-filename (buffer-file-name))
      (current-line (line-number-at-pos))
      (current-column (- (point) (line-beginning-position))))

    (when
      (if branch
        (vc-root-version-diff nil branch nil)
        (vc-root-diff nil))
      (when current-filename
        (let*
          (
            (current-filename-relative (file-relative-name current-filename default-directory))
            (point-found (diff-at-point-file-line-to-point current-filename-relative current-line current-column)))
          ;; Go to the file in the diff which we were previously viewing.
          (when point-found
            (goto-char point-found)))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit, I've since written made a version of this which parses the diff hunks, [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51439/2418).

---

*Posting own answer, it works but it has some limitations.*

This is a wrapper for `vc-root-diff` which opens a fillscreen buffer, and jumps to the current file then the line/column (using search).

Ideally it would position the cursor using the diff line ranges, as long as you're on a unique within the file.

```lisp
;; Override pop-up-windows,
(defun vc-root-diff-fullscreen-and-jump-to-point () "
Open a diff of the repository in the current frame.
Jumping to the file, then line if possible.
"
  (interactive)
  (let
    (
      (pop-up-windows nil)
      (current-filename (buffer-file-name))
      ;; TODO, parse the diff chunks instead of searching for plain text.
      ;; not urgent.
      (current-line
        (buffer-substring-no-properties
          (line-beginning-position)
          (line-end-position)))

      ;; Chars to move backwards (so we keep the same relative point).
      (point-offset (- (save-excursion (end-of-line) (point)) (point)))

      )
    (when (vc-root-diff nil)
      ;; It's possible we don't have a file.
      (when current-filename
        ;; Go to the file in the diff which we were previously viewing.
        (let ((current-filename-rel (file-relative-name current-filename default-directory)))
          (when
            (search-forward-regexp
              (concat
                "^"
                ;; Prefix '--- '.
                "\\-\\-\\-[[:blank:]]+.*\n"
                ;; Prefix '+++ '.
                "\\+\\+\\+[[:blank:]]+"
                ;; Optional 'b/'.
                "\\(\\|b/\\)"
                (regexp-quote current-filename-rel)
                ;; Optional ' (some text)'
                ;; Subversion quirk.
                "\\(\\|[[:blank:]]+.*\\)\n"
                "@@[[:blank:]]+.*@@"
                ;; may have trailing text, ignore this.
                )
              nil t 1
              )

            ;; Now search for the current line.
            (when
              (search-forward-regexp
                (concat
                  ;; Space or '+' line prefix.
                  "^\\( \\|\\+\\)"
                  (regexp-quote current-line)
                  "$"
                  )
                nil t 1
                )
              (backward-char point-offset)
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Your "Subversion quirk" is presumably wrong.  That's optionally matching one-or-more space chars followed by zero-or-more chars which are neither a backslash nor the letter `n`.

Comment: I would imagine you intended to use `[^\n]*` there, to say "zero or more non-newlines" (in a double-quoted string `\n` is a newline), but you can write that as `.*`

Comment: Thanks, corrected.

Comment: Oh, and you probably wanted `[:blank:]` where you've used `[:space:]`, as the latter will match newline chars which I don't think you intended?  `blank` matches "horizontal whitespace".

Comment: Done, using only space for line prefix ` ` or `+`.

Comment: You might also like `rx` for writing and formatting readable regexps.  The following are going to look terrible as comments, but if you split them over multiple lines in Emacs they'll look much better.  See `C-h f rx` for the syntax. `rx` itself is a macro, so `rx-to-string` is needed here in order to process the dynamic parts at run-time.

Comment: `(rx-to-string '(sequence bol (one-or-more "+") (one-or-more (any blank)) (optional "b/") (eval current-filename-rel) (optional (sequence (one-or-more (any blank)) (zero-or-more not-newline))) eol) t)`

Comment: `(rx-to-string '(sequence bol (or " " "+") (eval current-line) eol) t)`

Comment: @phils unfortunately, the `eval` won't work with lexical binding. You should do ``(rx-to-string `(sequence ... ,current-line ...) t)`` instead. Or if you have Emacs 27 `(rx ... (literal current-line) ...)`.

Comment: Rather not use `rx-to-string`, it seems nice but it's a layer between me and regex I'd need to learn.

Comment: Yes, it's not for everyone, and being able to read and write raw regular expressions is definitely more important; but I'd suggest taking another look at `rx` at some point -- it can be very nice to work with.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't *exactly* the same as you've asked for, but you may like `vc-region-history` (bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> by default) or, if you're using Magit, the equivalent command `magit-log-buffer-file` (<kbd>l</kbd> in the `magit-file-popup` menu; hence commonly it would be <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>M-g</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>).

With these commands you firstly mark a *region* you are interested in, and they then give you (in a single buffer) a history of that region: the sequence of commits which affected the region, and the diff for each of those changes.

Give this a try and see if it suits your requirements.